# LinqToTwitter. Favorites - Obtain all

Tags: c#, api, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I have written the code for obtaining a set of a users favourites, however, what's not apparent is how I can page/cursor through these to obtain, say, a users very first set of favourites. The cursor value is always 0 and `max/since ID` are null. Is there a way of acheiving this using LinqToTwitter?

Answer (score 2):

For Favorites, you need to traverse the timeline with SinceID/MaxID. Here's an example:

```
    static async Task ShowFavoritesAsync(TwitterContext twitterCtx)
    {
        const int PerQueryFavCount = 200;

        // set from a value that you previously saved
        ulong sinceID = 1; 

        var favsResponse =
            await
                (from fav in twitterCtx.Favorites
                 where fav.Type == FavoritesType.Favorites &&
                       fav.Count == PerQueryFavCount
                 select fav)
                .ToListAsync();

        if (favsResponse == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No favorites returned from Twitter.");
            return;
        }

        var favList = new List<Favorites>(favsResponse);

        // first tweet processed on current query
        ulong maxID = favList.Min(fav => fav.StatusID) - 1;

        do
        {
            favsResponse =
                await
                    (from fav in twitterCtx.Favorites
                     where fav.Type == FavoritesType.Favorites &&
                           fav.Count == PerQueryFavCount &&
                           fav.SinceID == sinceID &&
                           fav.MaxID == maxID
                     select fav)
                    .ToListAsync();

            if (favsResponse == null || favsResponse.Count == 0) break;

            // reset first tweet to avoid re-querying the
            // same list you just received
            maxID = favsResponse.Min(fav => fav.StatusID) - 1;
            favList.AddRange(favsResponse);

        } while (favsResponse.Count > 0);

        favList.ForEach(fav => 
        {
            if (fav != null && fav.User != null)
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Name: {0}, Tweet: {1}",
                    fav.User.ScreenNameResponse, fav.Text);
        });

        // save this in your db for this user so you can set
        // sinceID accurately the next time you do a query
        // and avoid querying the same tweets again.
        ulong newSinceID = favList.Max(fav => fav.SinceID);
    }
```

I wrote a blog post that explains how to work with Twitter Timelines. It was written for an earlier non-async version of LINQ to Twitter, but the concepts remain the same:

[Working with Timelines with LINQ to Twitter](http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2012/09/02/working-with-timelines-with-linq-to-twitter.aspx)

This is based on Twitter's guidance, which is a good read:

[Twitter's Working with Timelines Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines)